# ASF4 SamD Flash program Execution from RAM

Tags: c, bootloader, atmel, atmelstudio

I am using Microchip Studio IDE with ASF4 for development in SAMD21

I would like to add provision to update bootloader from bootloader. For this we need bootloader to execute form RAM. What all modifications we need for this?

I have modified loader file(.ld) and made sure that all sections(text stack bss etc) are in RAM. I have verified that binary generated contains RAM addresses. Do we need code modifications to load sections from flash to RAM?

I have referred [attached](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-42249-Executing-code-from-RAM_Application-Note_AT07347.pdf) document for the modifications

Can anyone share what code modifications are needed along with loader file modification.

Comment: From what I recall you have separate flash banks on this chip. If so, it would be possible to upload the bootloader in a different flash bank which is a much better solution than executing from RAM. You can have multiple bootloaders in multiple banks even, at least temporarily.

Comment: @Lundin Model I am using have 128KB of Flash and 16KB of SRAM and I cannot find anything about separate flash banks in datasheet. I will check again

Comment: Ok because I have a D20 project where we picked the part specifically since it had decent data flash emulation and we write to flash in run-time, from code executing in flash. Similarly, you should be able to upload a bootloader in such flash and program the main flash from there.